# Accessing the physics body to a group in Phaser 3

Tags: physics, phaser-framework

I am making a game where a chicken is dropping eggs from the sky. However I am having trouble getting the eggs to ‘fall’. I added it as a group with physics enabled. But I cant seem to get the ‘body’ property to come back as anything as null. Here is the relevant code:

```js
class Egg extends Phaser.GameObjects.Sprite {
    constructor(scene) {
        var x = scene.chicken.x;
        var y = scene.chicken.y + 80;

        super(scene, x, y, "egg");

        // Add the egg to the scene
        scene.add.existing(this);
        this.play("egg_anim");

        // enable physics
        scene.physics.world.enableBody(this);

        this.body.velocity.y = -250;

        // Add the beam to the projectiles group in scene 2
        scene.projectiles.add(this);
    }
}
```

And this is how I add it to the projectiles group:

```js
this.projectiles = this.physics.add.group();
```

thanks so much!

Comment: One thing is that i believe -250 y is having eggs travel up, not down

Comment: Could you share your game config?